# Unable to run django project due to error in manage.py file

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am working on django project. My python version is 2.7.15 and django version is 1.11.29. When I am trying to execute

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

I am getting error as follows -

```
File "manage.py", line 17
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

to solve this I removed **from exc** and run again then it throws error as follows -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 13, in main
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

May be the similar questions already available on stackoverflow itself but these solutions are not working in my case hence I am asking wrt my problem. Please suggest me how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: django-admin --version
use this command and check django is installed or not make sure to activate virtual environment first if you are using

Comment: Did you activate your virtualenv? check whether django is installed.

Comment: after running django-admin --version I got version as 3.1.2

Comment: Do you use virtual environment? if you do you probably haven't activate the environment yet

Comment: @kimhongMuong I am not using virtual environment